# How to pass variables from an array to ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

**Problem**: I have a list of data that has an ID in each record which I use to make an API call to get more info about this particular item. Problem is - ng-repeat already is looping through my data. How do I pass a different API call's response for each ng-repeat action?

**Code**:

**View**:

```
<div ng-repeat="activity in userActivity">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
            <a href="#">{[ user.fullname ]}</a> has {[ activity.action ]} to: <a href="#"> {[ post.post ]}<br>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Angular Controller**:

```
profileApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams){
$scope.user = [];
$scope.userActivity = [];
$scope.post = [];

$http.get('/api/user', {params: { id: $routeParams.id }})
    .success(function(res){
        $scope.user = res.user;
        $scope.userActivity = res.user.activity;

        $http.get('/api/post', {params: { postID: $scope.userActivity[0].post }})
            .success(function(res){
                $scope.post = res.post;
        })
            .error(function(data, status){
                console.log(data);
        });

    })
    .error(function(data, status){
        console.log(data);
    });
}]);
```

The /api/user's activity from the response looks like this:

```
"activity": [
    {
        "post": "123456781",
        "action": "agreed"
    },
    {
        "post": "123456782",
        "action": "disagreed"
    }
]
```

So can someone please help and point me to the right direction as to how to get the data populated together with the ng-view? Currently, it is just showing the post.post for 123456781 which makes sense but how do I pass the variables to the ng-repeat for such a case?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.user.activity` is an **array**,

so first loop through the `$scope.userActivity` array an then make an `api call` for each value in array and then, update the `$scope.userActivity` array with a new key as `post_obj` which is the response you will be using in the view.

Then, your controller should be changed to,

```
profileApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams){
$scope.user = [];
$scope.userActivity = [];
$scope.post = [];

$http.get('/api/user', {params: { id: $routeParams.id }})
    .success(function(res){
        $scope.user = res.user;
        $scope.userActivity = res.user.activity;

        for(var i=0 ; i < $scope.userActivity.length ; i++)
        {
            $http.get('/api/post', {params: { postID: $scope.userActivity[i].post }})
                .success(function(res){
                    $scope.userActivity[i].post_obj = res.post;
            })
                .error(function(data, status){
                    console.log(data);
            });
        }



    })
    .error(function(data, status){
        console.log(data);
    });
}]);
```

Then, your view should change to,

```
<div ng-repeat="activity in userActivity">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
            <a href="#">{{ user.fullname }}</a> has {{ activity.action }} to: <a href="#"> {{ activity.post_obj }}<br>
        </div>
    </div
 </div>
```

**This userActivity array now contain the post_obj which we got in response corresponding to each post**

Comment: Sorry I had just edited the original post. I made a mistake in explaining my problem. When I do this, it always shows me the first item and it doesn't pass the variables as it should when ng-repeat is executing

Comment: The $scope.post which shall be updating for each item in /api/user's activity. Essentially, this is how it is supposed to work: Get post (better name would've been postID) from user's activity, which is a unique key which I use to make an API call to /api/post with the param with the post (which is the ID). Hope this clears up

Comment: ok, I understood your requirement, give me two mins time, I will frame an answer

Comment: I had to tweak it a little but it worked in the end. So the variable "i" wasn't working so I made it into an IIFE and it did the trick.

Thanks a lot for your help! Your trick to put the response's variables into the scope.userActivity array will be something I am gonna carry on needing in my project. Highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
ng-repeat="activity in userActivity" ng-click="myFunction(activity)"
```

Create myFunction in controller, which gets only clicked activity.

Comment: Actually I didn't get this to be honest. Anyhow, the question has been answered. Thanks for your input